# В чем проблема? Когда я компилирую, выдает ошибку

Tags: webpack

**Ошибка:**

```
Error: options/query cannot be used with loaders (use options for each array item) in {
  "test": {},
  "exclude": {},
  "loader": [
    "babel-loader"
  ],
  "query": {
    "presets": [
      "latest",
      "stage-0",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Конфиг webpack:**

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output:{
        path: "/src/js",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "js",
    },
    devServer:{
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "./src",
        port: 3000,
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: ["babel-loader"],
                query: {
                    presets: ["latest","stage-0", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `loader` должен быть просто строкой (`loader: "babel-loader"`), а не массивом строк. Или должно быть `loaders: ["массив", "строк"]`